# Validating forms in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, validation, formvalidation-plugin

Is there a standard way to validate forms in reactjs?

The form is fairly simple but have to validate a string (length) an int and they are all required.

Have seen things like this but they seem a bit bloated.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator
```

Am really just looking for a standard method, or official package but there does not seem to be one.

Comment: There is no standard. Just choose one of the many libraries or do you it yourself. maybe https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik

Comment: if it is fairly simple validation as in your case, why do you need a library? Have a separate controlled component for your textbox and do the necessary validation in the onChange handler using a regex. You could pass the length for each field as a prop.

Comment: I prefer using validator for all of my forms. That being said, the “required” attribute is honored in react. Just as a side note. Nevertheless, I use validator to check the value in the form submit handler (or individual onChange events if needed) be sure to ‘preventDefault’ if you decide to validate on the form submit.